# How do I get my UV islands to be symmetrical? Why is my unwrap asymmetrical?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

[image]

I've checked that the model itself is actually symmetrical. I even deleted half then mirrored and applied to make sure and the face still comes out crooked in the unwrap.